# Y combinator as an application of Lawvere's fixed point theorem

Tags: category-theory, fixed-point-theorems, lambda-calculus

[Lawvere's fixed point theorem](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Lawvere%27s+fixed+point+theorem) states that that in a cartesian closed category, if there is a morphism $ϕ: A \to B^A$ which is point-surjective (i.e., for every point $q : 1 \to B^A$ there exists a point $p : 1 \to A$ such that $ϕp = q$), then every endomorphism $f : B \to B$ has a fixed point.

The fixed point of $f$ is obtained as $ϕ(p)(p)$ where $p : 1 \to A$ is the point of $A$ such that $ϕp = q$ for $q : 1 \to B^A$ defined in lambda calculus notation as $q = λa:A.fϕ(a)(a)$.

I've seen it remarked several times that the existence of Y combinator in lambda calculus, i.e., $Y = λf.(λx.f(xx))(λx.f(xx))$, is an application of Lawvere's fixed point theorem, but the remark has always been made only in passing and I haven't been able to figure out precisely how to get from the one to the other.

Can someone help me out by making the application explicit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What Scott did with [domain theory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/domain+theory) was construct a cartesian closed category with $\varphi:D\cong D^D$. More generally, we have an retraction, i.e. split epimorphism, $D\to D^D$. Isomorphisms/split-epimorphisms are clearly point-surjective: simply set $p = \varphi^{-1}\circ q$.

We can actually arrange for $\varphi=id_D$ for some models of the untyped lambda calculus. Then the fixed point of $f$ by the above statement would be $(p\,p)$ where $p=q=\lambda x.f(x\,x)$, i.e. $$\mathsf{fix}\,f = (\lambda x.f(x\,x))(\lambda x.f(x\,x))$$ which we, of course, lambda abstract to get $$\mathsf{fix}=\lambda f.(\lambda x.f(x\,x))(\lambda x.f(x\,x))$$
Not assuming $\varphi=id_D$ adds some noise but just as easily leads to the appropriate expression. For example, in Haskell if you wanted to model the untyped lambda calculus, you could use:

```
newtype D = D {unD :: D -> D}
```

The data constructor `D` corresponds to $\varphi^{-1}$ with `unD` corresponding to $\varphi$ witnessing `D ≅ (D -> D)`. It's an easy enough exercise to insert the uses of `D` and `unD`, more or less guided by the types, into the expression for the $Y$ combinator to get a type checking version in Haskell. In practice, you'd probably want some kind of "base type" so you can actually observe something from these values. This would produce a type like:

```
data D b = Base b | Fun (D b -> D b)
```

Here `Fun` plays the role of $\varphi^{-1}$ and `unFun (Fun f) = f` plays the role of $\varphi$ and we only have a retraction. (To make `unFun` total you can make `unFun` send `Base b` to any value of `D -> D`, though bottom *is* a value and not so dismissable anyway given the context of the problem.)

Answer (score 1):

**Lawvere's Fixed Point Theorem:**
$$
X\times X\xrightarrow{f} Y\\
\Delta\uparrow\qquad\;\;\downarrow\alpha\\
\;\;\;X\;\; \xrightarrow[g]\;\; Y
$$
For sets $X, Y$, functions $f: X\times X\to Y$, $\alpha: Y\to Y$, let $g := \alpha\circ f\circ\Delta$. If $g$ is representable by $f(-,\ulcorner g\urcorner)$, then $\alpha$ has a fixed point: $\alpha\big(f\left(\ulcorner g\urcorner,\ulcorner g\urcorner\right)\big)=g\left(\ulcorner g\urcorner\right)=f\left(\ulcorner g\urcorner,\ulcorner g\urcorner\right)$.

Now let's fit Curry's $Y$ combinator into Lawvere's schema.
$$
\Lambda\times \Lambda \xrightarrow{f} \Lambda \\
\Delta\uparrow\qquad\;\;\downarrow\alpha_y\\
\;\;\;\Lambda\;\; \xrightarrow[g]\;\; \Lambda
$$

where $\Lambda$ is the class of lambda terms, and $f:(x,y)\mapsto yx$, and $\alpha_y: x\mapsto yx$.

then $g=\lambda x.y(xx)$ is a fixed point of $\alpha_y$:
$$
gg=\alpha_y(gg)
$$

**Curry's $Y$ combinator is**

$$
Y := \lambda y.gg=\lambda y.(\lambda x.y(xx))(\lambda x.y(xx))
$$

If we let $f:(x,y)\mapsto \lambda v.yxv$, and $\alpha_y: x\mapsto yx$, then
$$
g=\lambda x.y(\lambda v.xxv)
$$
and $gg=\alpha_y(gg)$.

Now we get **the call-by-value version of $Y$ combinator:**
$$
\lambda y.gg=\lambda y.(\lambda x.y(\lambda v.xxv))(\lambda x.y(\lambda v.xxv))
$$

If we let $f:(x,y)\mapsto yx$, and $\alpha: x\mapsto\lambda y.y(xy)$, then
$$
g=\lambda xy.y(xxy)\\
gg=\alpha(gg)
$$

Now we get **Turing's $\Theta$ combinator:**
$$
\Theta := gg=(\lambda xy.y(xxy))(\lambda xy.y(xxy))
$$

**The call-by-value version of $\Theta$ combinator** is similar.

Let $f:(x,y)\mapsto yx$, and $\alpha: x\mapsto\lambda y.y(\lambda z.xyz)$.

$$g=\lambda xy.y(\lambda z.xxyz)\\
gg=\alpha(gg)\\
gg=(\lambda xy.y(\lambda z.xxyz))(\lambda xy.y(\lambda z.xxyz))
$$

Comment: The question is asking about Lawvere's fixed point theorem, which you haven't addressed.

Comment: @Zhen Lin Sorry, I forgot to address Lawvere's fixed point theorem.